# Average amount of water in different sized cups randomly filled from a limited water source

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference

I have 3 cups. Cup 1 can hold 1 ml of water. Cup 2 can hold 5 ml of water. Cup 3 can hold 10 ml of water.
I only have 12 ml of water.

If I distribute water to each cup randomly what is the average amount of water in each cup once I’ve distributed all the water?

I tried to set this up as a set of algebraic equations like:

C1 + C2 + C3 = 12

0 ≤ C1 ≤ 1

0 ≤ C2 ≤ 5

0 ≤ C3 ≤ 10

Then solving numerically. We assume the water is infinitely divisible and because of this there seems to be an infinite set of solutions to these equations. When I change the starting point of the numerical solver I often get results around:

C1 = 0.833

C2 = 3.833

C3 = 7.333

Is there a way to calculate the exact statistical averages?

Answer (score 1):

The equation and three inequalities together define a rectangle with vertices $(c_1,c_2,c_3) = (1,1,10)$ and $(0,2,10)$ and $(0,5,7)$ and $(1,4,7)$, so perhaps you mean the distribution should be uniform on that rectangle; in that case the average values would be $(0.5,3,8.5)$ respectively (the center of the rectangle). The fact that you're getting values close to $(\frac56,3\frac56,7\frac13)$ suggests, however, that you're using some different distribution or sampling method. Without defining exactly what "randomly" means, it's impossible to answer this question.

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for the quick answer - I was just manually changing the starting point for each cup in the numerical solver and so there's inherent bias. When I say randomly distributed I mean take a jug with 12 ml of water then randomly choose a cup and then fill it with an infinitely small amount of water, then choose another cup at random and fill that cup with an infinitely small amount of water and so on until all the water is distributed. Would your rectangle solution generalise to the case of n cups of k sizes?

Comment: @luke Won't you end up with all three cups filling at equal "speed" until the smallest one is full? Then you can only randomly choose between the two bigger cups, which will fill at equal speed, so you will end up with the second full and then third will be the only one left to fill. So it looks to me you would always have the result $(1,5,6)$. What am I not getting?

Comment: Oh that’s interesting – I didn’t think of it like that. Perhaps I’ve posed the question wrong. In your analogy @Stinking Bishop isn’t there a chance that one of the cups was never chosen to be filled? So wouldn’t there be a possibility that we’d end up with e.g. C1 = 0, C2 = 2, and C3 = 10? It might be a very small possibility but it is still quantifiable?

Comment: If "infinitely small amount of water" is to mean anything, it would mean in the limit as the number of random choices goes to infinity—and then by the law of large numbers, with probability $1$ it would act like equal filling speeds. More importantly, if one wants quantifiable probabilities, then one needs to define a quantitative probability model, not just an idea of a model.